# Lua script: Convert currency to number

Tags: lua

I'm a bit new to Lua, and trying to convert currency to a number. I tried `tonumber()` but that doesn't seem to be working.

How would I get Lua to convert a value like "$1,000" to "1000"?

Thanks!

Comment: use `tonumber` but remove the `$` and `,` from the string first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tonumber` you just need to remove the formatting from the string first.

```
local str = "$1,000"
str = str:gsub(',','')
str = str:gsub('%$','') -- the `%` is needed to escape the `$`

local num = tonumber(str)
print(num == 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but I think I got something that works.

```
formattednum = string.gsub(numberofshirts, "%,", "")
nodollar = string.gsub(formattednum, "%$", "")
```